# Minimal set of test cases with modified condition/decision coverage

Tags: testing, code-coverage, mc-dc

I have a question regarding modified condition/decision coverage that I can't figure out.

So if I have the expression `((A || B) && C)` and the task is with a minimal number of test cases receive 100% MD/DC.

I break it down into two parts with the minimal number of test cases for `(A || B)` and `(X && C)`.

```
(A || B) : {F, F} = F, {F, T} = T, {T, -} = T
(X && C) : {F, -} = F, {T, F} = F, {T, T} = T
```

The '-' means that it doesn't matter which value they are since they won't be evaluated by the compiler.

So when I combine these I get this as my minimal set of test cases:

```
((A || B) && C) : {{F, F}, -} = F, {{F, T}, F} = F, {{T, -}, T} = T
```

But when I google it this is also in the set: `{{F, T}, T} = T` 
Which I do not agree on because I tested the parts of this set separately in the other tests, didn't I?

So I seem to miss what the fourth test case adds to the set and it would be great if someone could explain why I must have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for MC/DC you need for every condition P (A/B/C in your case) two test cases T and T' so that P is true in T and false in T', and so that the outcome of the predicate is true in one and false in the other test case.

An MC/DC cover for ((A || B) && C) is:

- T1: (F, F, T) -> F (your first test case)
- T2: (F, T, T) -> T (B flips outcome compared to T1, missing)
- T3: (T, F, T) -> T (A flips outcome compared to T1, your third test case)
- T4: (F, T, F) -> F (C flips outcome compared to T2, your second test case)

In concrete test cases you cannot have "-" / don't-care values: You must make a choice when you exercise the system.

So what you are missing in your answer is a pair of two test cases (T1 and T2) in which flipping only the second condition B also flips the outcome.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, a little explanation on MCDC

To achieve MCDC you need to find at least one Test Pair for each condition in your boolean expression that fulfills the MCDC criterion.

At the moment there are 3 types of MCDC defined and approved by certification bodies (e.g. FAA)

1. "Unique Cause" – MCDC (original definition):  Only one, specifically the influencing condition may change between the two test values of the test pair. The resulting decision, the result of the boolean expression, must also be different for the 2 test values of the test pair. All other conditions in the test pair must be fixed and unchanged.
2. "Masking" – MCDC”:  Only one condition of the boolean expression having an influence on the outcome of the decision may change. Other conditions may change as well, but must be masked. Masked means, using the boolean logic in the expression, they will not have an influence on the outcome. If the left side of an AND is FALSE, then the complete rightside expression and sub expressions do not matter. They are masked. Masking is a relaxation of the “Unique Cause”MCDC.
3. "Unique Cause + Masking" – MCDC. This is a hybrid and especially needed for boolean expressions with strongly coupled conditions like for example in “ab+ac”. It is not possible to find a test pair for condition “a” the fulfills "Unique Cause" – MCDC. So, we can relax the original definition, and allow masking for strongly coupled conditions.

With these 2 additional definitions much more test pairs can be found.

Please note additionally that, when using languages with a boolean short cut evaluation strategy (like Java, C, C++), there are even more test pairs fulfilling MCDC criteria.

Very important is to understand that a BlackBox view on a truth table does not allow to find any kind of Masking or boolean short cut evaluation.

MCDC is a structural coverage metric and so a WhiteBox View on the boolean expression is absolutely mandatory.

So, now to your expression: “(a+b)c”. A brute force analysis with boolean shortcut evaluation will give you the following test pairs for your 3 conditions a,b,c:

```
Influencing Condition: 'a'  Pair:  0,  5   Unique Cause
Influencing Condition: 'a'  Pair:  0,  7   Unique Cause
Influencing Condition: 'a'  Pair:  1,  5   Unique Cause
Influencing Condition: 'a'  Pair:  1,  7   Unique Cause
Influencing Condition: 'b'  Pair:  0,  3   Unique Cause
Influencing Condition: 'b'  Pair:  1,  3   Unique Cause
Influencing Condition: 'c'  Pair:  2,  3   Unique Cause
Influencing Condition: 'c'  Pair:  2,  5   Masking
Influencing Condition: 'c'  Pair:  2,  7   Masking
Influencing Condition: 'c'  Pair:  3,  4   Masking
Influencing Condition: 'c'  Pair:  3,  6   Masking
Influencing Condition: 'c'  Pair:  4,  5   Unique Cause
Influencing Condition: 'c'  Pair:  4,  7   Unique Cause
Influencing Condition: 'c'  Pair:  5,  6   Unique Cause
Influencing Condition: 'c'  Pair:  6,  7   Unique Cause
```

Without a white box view, you will never find “Unique Cause” – MCDC test pairs like 0,7 for condition “a”. Also, you will not find any of the valid "Masking" – MCDC” test pairs.

The next step is now to find one minimum test set. This can be done by applying the “set cover” or “unate covering” algoritm. From above test pairs we can create a table that shows which test value covers what condition. In your case this looks like the following:

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
a  X X       X   X 
b  X X   X         
c      X X X X X X
```

Simple elimination of double columns will already reduce the table to

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7             0 3 5
a  X -       X   -     ==>   a  X   X
b  X -   X                   b  X X
c      - X - X - -           c    X X
```

Please Note: We employed some heuristics to select, which of completely identical columns should be eliminated. So effectively there are more solutions to the set cover problem. But with the geometrically growth on computing time and memory consumption related to the number of conditions, this is the only meaningful approach.

Now we will apply Petrick’s method and find out all coverage sets:

```
1.    0, 3 
2.    0, 5 
3.    3, 5
```

That means, we need to select, out of the above test pair list, test pairs for a,b,c that contain, for solution 1,  0 and 3,   for solution 2,   0 and 5,    and for solution 3    3  and  5

Also here we will apply some heuristic functions to come up with the minimum solutions:

```
-------- For Coverage set   1

Test Pair for Condition 'a':    0   5   (Unique Cause)
Test Pair for Condition 'b':    0   3   (Unique Cause)
Test Pair for Condition 'c':    2   3   (Unique Cause)

Resulting Test Vector:  0 2 3 5 


-------- For Coverage set   2

Test Pair for Condition 'a':    0   5   (Unique Cause)
Test Pair for Condition 'b':    0   3   (Unique Cause)
Test Pair for Condition 'c':    5   6   (Unique Cause)

Resulting Test Vector:  0 3 5 6 


-------- For Coverage set   3    

Test Pair for Condition 'a':    1   5   (Unique Cause)
Test Pair for Condition 'b':    1   3   (Unique Cause)
Test Pair for Condition 'c':    5   6   (Unique Cause)


Resulting Test Vector:  1 3 5 6 

---------------------------------------
Test vector: Recommended Result: 0 2 3 5 

    0:  a=0  b=0  c=0    (0)
    2:  a=0  b=1  c=0    (0)
    3:  a=0  b=1  c=1    (1)
    5:  a=1  b=0  c=1    (1)
```

You see that you have for all 3 possible solutions 4 test cases that cover all conditions and that fulfill MCDC criteria. If you check publications in the internet, then you will see that the minimum number of tests is  n+1 (n = number of conditions). This sounds not like a great achievement. But looking at MCC (Multiple Condition Coverage) you will have 2^n test cases. So, for 8 conditions 256 test cases. With MCDC there will be only 9. That was one reason to come up with MCDC.

I created also a software to help to better understand MCDC coverage. It uses a boolean expression as input, simplifies that (if you wish) and calculates all MCDC test pairs.

You may find it here:

[MCDC](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/MCDC)

I hope, I could shed some light on the topic. I am happy to answer further questions.

Comment: What a wonderful explanation. I am completely impressed.

Comment: out of three possible solution which is the better 0235 or 0356 or 1356

Comment: Basically it does not matter. They will all work. You may use some heuristic for selecting. For example, minimum set bits or cleared bits, or the number of changed bits. But, no preference.

Comment: U eleminated the double  Coloumns what logic u used?? And when selecting the pair according to your point number 1 .  you told that only one variable among 3 variables should change from true to false or vise versa and also the out come need to be changed. But in pair 0,5 both A and C are changed. Can you elobarate this point.

Comment: This is hard to explain in a comment. Please google for "reduction of prime implicant tables"

Answer (score 0):

For MCDC to be achieved it requires the output to change when there is a change in only 1 input  while the other inputs remain constant. For example in your case

**MCDC for (A || B) & C**

[image]

So when A changes from 1 to 0 B & C remain constant whereas output changes from 1 to 0. Same applies for both B & C.

**Normally they say the minimum number of steps to achieve MCDC is Number of Inputs + Number of Outputs.**

So in your case MCDC can be achieved in minimum of 4 steps.